# SQL+ Select highest 5 number of entries and display in ascending order

Tags: oracle

so far i am able to select the highest 5 entries by putting them in descending order

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, COMMISSION_PCT 

FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE JOBID = 'SALES' AND ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY COMMISSION DESC
/
```

This works fine for selecting the highest entries but how would i put them in ascending order? (WITHOUT CHANGING THE OUTPUT TO THE 5 lOWEST VALUES)
thanks

Comment: If i put ASC then it will display the 5 lowest values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that does not work fine for selecting highest entries. Your query grabs the first 5 rows in any order, and orders them by commission, it is a very common mistake with `rownum`.

You need to order by first and after that you can use rownum:

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT LAST_NAME, COMMISSION_PCT 
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE JOBID = 'SALES' order by commission_pct desc
)
where rownum <= 5
order by commission_pct;
```

Or:

```
select last_name, commission_pct from 
(
  SELECT LAST_NAME, COMMISSION_PCT, rank() over (order by commission_pct desc) as rn 
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE JOBID = 'SALES'
)
where rn <= 5
order by commission_pct;
```

Or 12c+:

```
select * from (
select last_name, commission_pct 
FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE JOBID = 'SALES'
order by commission_pct desc fetch first 5 rows only)
order by commission_pct;
```